# fish shell | config file [conf.ls] not found

Tags: terminal, macros, console, ls, fish

When I run `ls -la` or `la` and some other functions aliases in fish I get an error.

`config file [conf.ls] not found`.

I have tried reinstalling fish shell and running `fish_update_completions` without success.

Comment: A quick [google search](https://www.google.co.il/search?q="conf.ls") suggests that this is a configuration file for [grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc). Perhaps you need to reinstall/update it or if you were getting rid of it, make sure there are no leftovers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fish doesn't know about any "conf.ls", so this is likely in your customization.

I suggest checking the output of `type ls` - whatever that is calling checks for a "conf.ls".

Comment: The problem was with "grc" library which I had to reinstall.